# Service Wire Type coming out of weatherhead

Tags: wiring

Is this the correct wire type to use for my 24" pig tails coming out of the weatherhead to connect to the service drop coming from the power pole?
I'm worried that this wire is not suppose to be outside in the environment, even thought it's just 24" in length and in the air, coming out of the weatherhead.

The electrical store gave me this type of aluminum wire for my pig tails coming out of my weatherhead.  I'm using 125 amps.  I'm worried it could be the wrong ones.  The power company is coming out in a few days to connect and I don't want to run into issues.  See pictures below, but it says:

Alumaflex (R) AA8176 Type THWN-2 or THHN or Gasoline and oil resistant II for CT use sunlight resistant

Southwire S/N..?.. (TM) E23919 (UL) 600 volts (AWG 1/0) 53,508 mm2..?..

I guess I need a service entrance wire, type SE?
Or is this the correct wire?:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-1000-ft-1-0-1-0-2-Black-Stranded-AL-Triplex-URD-Brenau-Cable-55415201/204788216?keyword=1000048075

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If a *proper electrical supply house* sold it to you, most likely it's right.  That's one of the merits of buying from them, instead of Home Depot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean in conduit up to the weatherhead the that is perfectly fine. It has a W rating (THWN) for wet location and is sunlight resistant.

Comment: The wire travels from the meter socket, up the conduit, and out of the weatherhead 24".  It should be okay? Water and sunlight resistant is key?

Comment: Yup. You're fine.